# Flutter sort accent characters

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to sort hungarian String textes in a list, but i ran into a problem with accent characters.

For example:

final textList = ["Bb", "Aa", "Áa"];

textList.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));

Output: ["Aa", "Bb", "Áa"]

But the current output have to be this: ["Aa", "Áa", "Bb"].

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986738/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-with-german-umlauts-in-dart

Comment: not nice solutions... In fact, half of them are really bad solution. Flutter not handle culture during sort?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic might be the best solution for you for now. Flutter (Dart) does not have any string sorting based on culture, as far as I know. Sorting is usually done by ASCII code or Unicode.

Comment: Unfortunatelly Diacritic package not solve my problem because it only change accent characters to non-accent characters and "E" and "É" will be equal.

Comment: You can use it like shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65736263/6704033 It should do what you want it to do.

Comment: diacritic is not a solution for me. It just replace accent characters to non-accent in sort process. It does not make difference between “e” and “é”